# CiviCRM won't load at all, shows "DB error: unknown error"

Tags: error, dashboard

CiviCRM suddenly stopped loading. I am running CiviCRM version 4.5.5 on Drupal version 7.4.4.

As far as I know, no changes were made to CiviCRM or Drupal, but obviously something happened. The dashboard won't load, and when I found an old page in my history and loaded it, it worked but trying to navigate gives me the message "Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again." I know the data is in the database because I can access it through PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: If you have access to the server, take a look at CiviCRM's log, which will probably be in yoursiteroot/sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog. There'll probably be some clues there.